# Does memcmp only work with strings?

Tags: c, memcmp

If I send `memcmp` two pointers to integers, then it seems to interpret the integers as chars.

For example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 256;
int res = memcmp(&a,&b,sizeof(int));
```

In the code above, it returns 1.

I'd like to get a better understanding of this function, and I am wondering if I'm either using it wrong or if there is a similar function for comparing blocks of memory holding `int` values.

Comment: What is wrong with reading the manual page - http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp

Comment: Read the manual page as this has the answer

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that the size of an `int` is 4 bytes (which is mostly, though not always, the case):

- On a little-endian processor, you have:

  - `int a = 5;   // Lowest address to highest address 0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00`
  - `int b = 256; // Lowest address to highest address 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00`
- On a big-endian processor, you have:

  - `int a = 5;   // Lowest address to highest address 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x05`
  - `int b = 256; // Lowest address to highest address 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00`

---

Now, function `memcmp` compares each pair of bytes sequentially:

- If the byte of the first operand is larger than the byte of the second operand, then it return +1
- If the byte of the first operand is smaller than the byte of the second operand, then it return -1
- If it completes the comparison without encountering any such pair of bytes, then it returns 0

---

As you can see:

- On a little-endian processor, it will return +1 after comparing the first pair of bytes (0x05 > 0x00)
- On a big-endian processor, it will return -1 after comparing the third pair of bytes (0x00 < 0x01)

Comment: The idea is correct, but the result is not always exactly "+1" or "-1". Just its signal should be used (that is '[...] then it returns a positive number', '[...] then it returns a negative number').

Comment: @rslemos - Can you describe more on your comment? something missed?  I can see only ' [...] ' is this a copy paste error?

Answer (score 2):

`memcmp` will compare bytes (aka `char`). To know whether an `int` of x bytes will be bigger or smaller than the other you will need to know the endianess of its representation.

Why not just compare the `int`s directly?

```
*a > *b
*a < *b
*a == *b
*a != *b
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a system that stores integers in memory in little-endian format (i.e. 5 is `05 00 00 00` and 256 is `00 01 00 00`). When you `memcmp` these values, the first byte of the first value is greater than the first byte of the second value, so the return value is greater than 0.